# How to validate and close a new tab which appeared after clicking a link using Karate UI?

Tags: karate

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on a link which opens a new tab
2. Validate something on the page opened on and
3. Close it.

How to focus on the new tab ,validate something, focus back on main page and close the other tab using Karate UI?

I went wrong somewhere. Please assist

Karate version : **0.9.6**

Comment: I tried below
click("//a[@id='link']") --- It opens a new link
switchPage('carrers.com') --- Not sure if this happens
waitForText('body','something') --- not happening
switchPage('tst.com') -- not happening
close() # Close the new tab opened  -- not happening